# Store "Nº" before number in COBOL

Tags: cobol, cobol85

I need to store *Nº* before a number (integer), like `Nº423`.

I try:

- `77 SC PIC 'Nº'9 VALUE 423.`
- `77 SC PIC N9 VALUE 423.`

But I don't achieve it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    01  prefixed-number.
        05  the-prefix pic xx   value 'Nº'.
        05  the-number pic 999  value 423.
```

I suggest you familiarize yourself with your compiler's documentation on data definitions in COBOL, including the PICTURE clause and the USAGE clause.